# Align a navigation menu to the center

Tags: css, navigation

I need to get my navigation menu centered.

You can see my current menu at: 
www.financialconsultingcareers.com

Here is the code:

```
#hor_nav
{
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 32px;
    z-index: 1000;
    Margin-top: -25px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #254117; 
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

#hor_nav UL
{
     margin: 0; 
}

#hor_nav LI
{
    list-style: none;
    display: center;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: justify;
    border-right: 1px solid #000001;

    <!--left: 2.5%;-->

}

div.#hor_nav, ul.#hor_nav li.active a 
{
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#hor_nav LI A
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 18px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    text-align: justify;   
}

#hor_nav LI.active A
{
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    background-color: #254117;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;       
}

#hor_nav li:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

#hor_nav LI A:hover, 
#hor_nav LI:hover A, 
#hor_nav LI.sfHover A
{
    background: #828282;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: -4px;  
}

#hor_nav LI UL
{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: -999em;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#hor_nav LI UL UL
{
    margin: -31px 0 0 170px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#hor_nav LI:hover UL UL, 
#hor_nav LI:hover UL UL UL, 
#hor_nav LI:hover UL UL UL UL, 
#hor_nav LI.sfHover UL UL, 
#hor_nav LI.sfHover UL UL UL, 
#hor_nav LI.sfHover UL UL UL UL
{
    left: -999em;
}

#hor_nav LI LI
{
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    background: #CCC;
    width: 225px;  
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #888888;
}

#hor_navLI LI A, 
#hor_nav LI LI.active A, 
#hor_nav LI LI A:hover
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #828282;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#hor_nav LI LI A, 
#hor_nav LI.active LI A
{
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#hor_nav LI:hover UL, 
#hor_nav LI.sfHover UL
{
    left: 4px;
}

#hor_nav LI LI:hover UL, 
#hor_nav LI LI LI:hover UL, 
#hor_nav LI LI LI LI:hover UL, 
#hor_nav LI LI.sfHover UL, 
#hor_nav LI LI LI.sfHover UL, 
#hor_nav LI LI LI LI.sfHover UL
{
    left: 0;
}

#hor_nav LI
{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Format your code please!

Comment: Format in what way? I thought the format was pretty clean...

Comment: In my actual editor it is formatted the way you suggested. :)

Comment: Yeah, you should be careful when you copy the code. With good formatting of code a lot more people will read it and answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Obviously I'm a newb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not solve everything, but if you add a fixed width (say, `width: 700px`) to the `<ul class="hor_nav">`, the menu is centered (however, the background does not persist through the full width of the page, but you have to set the background to a different element in order to support that).

You must specify a fixed width in order for `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to center the element.

There is no such thing as `position: center`. You can drop that one.

By the way, I notice the top logo is shrunk when you resize the page. Beware. ;)

Comment: I also notice the logo changes size... We will be changing alot over the next few weeks and that is one thing. 

Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Go check my page now and any suggestions on how to adjust the code so the text in the nav_menu is centered in the bar?

Comment: You set it to 700px... it is wider than the content (my suggestion was just an approximation). 671px seems to be the right width. Make sure the content fits in all of the browsers, though. You generally accept the first (earliest) answer that helped, by the way, but, no big deal. ;)

Comment: oops, sorry! It was definitely a team project and I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: No worries.. I don't care much about the votes and accepted answers. As long as we help each other out :)

Comment: Me, too, of course. I assumed it would be appropriate to point it out, since it is a new user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your navigation menu, you need to set a fixed width value to your UL. This is going to change how you implement your design though. So you may need to use the parent div in order to apply your border and background colors.

Comment: Ok, Thank you both for your answers. I addressed them as follows: I moved the design features to the UL element so that they applied better. It did a great job centering the bar on the page, but not the text inside the Nav Menu and that is my ultimate goal. Can you go check out the page and see the result and add other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a certain width. 100% would not work...

Example:

```
#hor_nav {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
```

The margin: 0 auto will centre it dead on but it will only work if you have a certain width applied to your element.

Comment: I esssentially did this by changing it to:

    #hor_nav
    {
    width: 100%;
     }



    #hor_nav UL
    {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  
    color: #000000;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 32px;
    z-index: 1000;
    Margin-top: -25px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #254117; 
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    }

Comment: Adjust your code to this;

`#hor_nav { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }`
`#hor_nav UL { width: 700px }`

Comment: I did, and the result is up... it does a great job centering the nav bar but not the nav text... I want the text center aligned inside the bar.

Comment: Try the code above. It will work. But the problem with that is, if you add more list items, things will go wrong and out of line.

Comment: I did a few tweaks to the code and got it to work how I wanted! Thank you!